# Clipboard paste through background page only works once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Converting my Firefox Extension to a web extension and running into trouble with pasting from the clipboard using FF 60.

I call the following function from my background script (where it is defined):

```
var readClipboard = function() {
  let txtToPaste = document.createElement('textarea');
  txtToPaste.id = "txtToPaste";
  document.body.appendChild(txtToPaste);

  txtToPaste.focus();

  let res = document.execCommand("paste");
  let result = txtToPaste.value;

  txtToPaste.parentNode.removeChild(txtToPaste);

  return result;
}
```

However, this only works once. When I click the button that calls this function, `res` will be true the first time, and false every subsequent time.

I've tried hardcoding the textarea into the background html page and do it that way, but no luck. Permissions etc must be right, because it works once.

EDIT:
I changed the code a bit so that it works in Chrome. It still does not work in FF.

Comment: Looks good to me per MDN.  Could try adding a catch statement to make sure it really is not pasting.

Comment: It's not, the execCommand call returns false. May be a Firefox bug...